# how to show only some fields of a collection after query in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have a query like below :

```
  $orders = Order::where('somefield', 12)->paginate(5)->groupBy('group_id');
        foreach ($orders as $order) {
          $order->put('shop', $order->groupBy('shop_id'));
           }
```

now what i want to do is to remove all fields from `$order` but the shop and this is how i have done that :

```
 $orders = Order::where('somefield', 12)->paginate(5)->groupBy('group_id');
        foreach ($orders as $order) {
          $order->put('shop', $order->groupBy('shop_id'));
            collect($order)->only('shop');
           }
```

so when i dd the `$order` here it shows only the shop index but when i return the `$orders`  it return with all the data . any idea what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: What else have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What **exactly** does `$orders` contain? An array of objects?

Comment: nicol i have wrote the order query its a collection that i have used groupby on it and i havent tried any thing else i mean i couldnt find any other way

Comment: If `$orders` contains a collection of objects, why do you want to modify the objects itself? "How to show only some fields" sounds like you should remove the unwanted fields from the template instead

Answer (score 1):

Use `select()` in your query
Like : `->select('your wanted field')`

Or Your can do this too :

```
$subset = $users->map(function ($user) {
return collect($user->toArray())
    ->only(['id', 'name', 'email'])
    ->all();
});
```